# model controller extend Yii 2 master controllers

Tags: controller, yii2-advanced-app

I am builting an application with yii2, and i am thinking to have a  master controller with the functions generated by GII (index, create, update and delete ) because all the models controllers have the same functions.

Is it a good idea or not ??

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If ure 101% sure that's u won't need any changes to each of them, then yes, otherwise just separate specific controllers and use one global for identical controllers.